# Meteor changing class of element to value of HTML

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am learning Meteor and building a To do app on my own. 90% complete but one last thing is hanging me up.

I was able to get the task class changed if the task is 'checked'.  Now I am trying to change the color of the task depending on the 'priority' set. The helper I am using for the template is:

```
Template.item.helpers({
isComplete: function () {// Set class according to status
    return this.checked ? 'complete' : '';
},
isChecked: function () {
    return this.checked ? 'checked' : false;
},
isPriority: function(){
    var priorityClass = $('#prioritySet').html();
    return priorityClass;
}
```

});

and here is part of the template code that applies.

```
 <a href="#"
           class="js-update-task-form {{isComplete}} {{isPriority}}"  >
            {{task}}
        </a>
```

The isProperty is the one that is not working properly. When the page loads it does not assign the proper class to the element, however if I update the task t change the 'priority' it will change the class to the one that was there before the change.

My question is. How can I get the value that is currently assigned to the '#prioritySet' html and and assign it as a class to the element.

I tried putting it in a ready function and that did not work.I also tried doing a Template*name*.rendered function and that did not work at all.

any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see you've answered this by changing how you're loading the priority. For an explanation of what's happening in your original question however, you're calling your Template's `isPriority` helper, which in turn is using jQuery to access to the DOM, before the DOM has actually been fully rendered. This means `$('#prioritySet').html()` will return `undefined`. Then after the DOM is loaded, the `isPriority` Template helper isn't called again since it isn't leveraging any type of reactive data source.

An alternative approach (for your original question) could be to only reference the DOM to get the `#prioritySet` value after the DOM has fully loaded, then store this result in a [ReactiveVar](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html). You could then return this `ReactiveVar` in your `isPriority` helper, which will make your helper behave reactively. So when the `ReactiveVar` is adjusted, your UI will update. Here's a quick example of this:

1) Make sure you have the `reactive-var` package installed: `meteor add reactive-var`.

2) Sample Template:

```
Template.item.onCreated(function onCreated() {
  this.prioritySet = new ReactiveVar();
});

Template.item.onRendered(function onRendered() {
  this.autorun(() => {
    this.prioritySet.set($('#prioritySet').html().trim());
  })
});

Template.item.helpers({
  ...
  isPriority() {
    return Template.instance().prioritySet.get();
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This is useful info I will be able to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Don't know why I didn't think of this before.

In the helper all I had to do was 'return this.priority' from the mongodb field so the code reads like this now.

```
Template.item.helpers({
isComplete: function () {// Set class according to status
    return this.checked ? 'complete' : '';
},
isChecked: function () {
    return this.checked ? 'checked' : false;
},
isPriority: function(){
    return this.priority;
}
```

});

Thanks for all who looked into solution.